# How to show Crashlytics issue with specific event_id?

Tags: android, firebase, google-bigquery, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

In my current project I'm exporting Android app's Crashlytics crash data to BigQuery. I'm trying to trace the issue with a native library, and multiple crashes from different native libraries are getting associated under the same issue id. I'm curious if there is a way to create a direct Firebase Crashlytics link to the issue's event with a crash `event_id`.

Right now Crashlytics issue links look like this:

```
<firebase_url>/<my_project_package>/issues/<issue_id>?sessionEventKey=<some_key>
```

`sessionEventKey` doesn't match the format the `event_id` from the BigQuery table, and `sessionEventKey`'s data doesn't match neither `issue_id` nor `event_id`. I tried to specify `eventId=<event_id>` HTTP query param, but that didn't work. So I'm wondering if there is a way to create a direct link based on `issue_id` + `event_id` I have in my crash data.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. Finally, I used event_timestamp to find the correct event, but obviously, it is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

This is the closest workaround you can get, in your query:

```
CONCAT("<firebase_url>/<project_package>/crashlytics/app/<app_name>/search?time=", UNIX_MILLIS(event_timestamp) - 1, ":", UNIX_MILLIS(event_timestamp) + 1000, "&q=", user.id) as issue_link
```

---

Doesn't seem like it is exactly possible (except for the above workaround), but here are my findings while trying to figure out a way, maybe someone else can take it further:

```
<firebase_url>/<project_package>/issues/<issue_id>?sessionEventKey=<session_event_key>
```

Here `session_event_key` is formed of 2 parts:

```
<session_event_key> => <user_based_hash_i_assume>_<event_id>
```

`event_id` we already have from BigQuery but the issue is the 32 character `user_based_hash_i_assume`, I found that for a particular `user_id` the `user_based_hash_i_assume` part is always the same across multiple issues for the same user, hence the assumption that it is probably a hash generated from the `user_id`.

I don't think there is a way to generate the `user_based_hash_i_assume` part with the information we have been provided. I made unsuccessful attempts with MD5 hash and few other hashing algorithms. Probably they are using some salt. Firebase team should have provided some way to open Crashlytics issues from BigQuery.